# SharePoint 2013 and ReportingServices2010 CreateDataSource Example

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, data-connection

Can anybody help me with how to use `CreateDataSource` with SharePoint 2013 to Create a Data Connection in C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample that is available in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createdatasource.aspx)

```
ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
rs.Url = "http://<Server Name>" + 
    "/_vti_bin/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx";
rs.Credentials = 
    System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

string name = "AdventureWorks.rsds";
string parent = "http://<Server Name>/Docs/Documents/";

// Define the data source definition.
DataSourceDefinition definition = new DataSourceDefinition();
definition.CredentialRetrieval = 
    CredentialRetrievalEnum.Integrated;
definition.ConnectString = 
    "data source=(local);initial catalog=AdventureWorks";
definition.Enabled = true;
definition.EnabledSpecified = true;
definition.Extension = "SQL";
definition.ImpersonateUserSpecified = false;
//Use the default prompt string.
definition.Prompt = null;
definition.WindowsCredentials = false;

try
{
    rs.CreateDataSource(name, parent, false, 
        definition, null);
}
catch (SoapException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerXml.ToString());
}
```